# Redirect ALL pages of site to page if using old IE browser - htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I'm trying to redirect all users using old versions of IE (7 and below) to an "upgrade your browser" page. The site is built using wordpress and none of teh things I have tired are working. the last this I tried was:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "MSIE [6-7]" [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http:/www.myurl.com/browser-redirect/index.html [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

And this isn't working. I've also tried this, and it causes a redirect loop, maybe because of WordPress?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "MSIE [6-7]" [NC]
Redirect 301 / http://www.myurl.com/browser-redirect/index.html
</IfModule>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT: The WordPress code which could be causing redirect errors?

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "MSIE [6-7]" [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/browser-redirect/index.html [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Things that were changed:

**RewriteRule ^(.*)$** - Targets all & any url from where this htaccess is.
 **Order** - because you have *[L]* at the end of your rewrites, means that if a url meets the conditions, it redirects, ignoring others. The Wordpress redirect would always win. So I've made the ie redirect the first to be checked.

*Yours forcefully,
Star Wars Pug*